# Using Jquery how can I find a table cell containing an element with the name property

Tags: jquery

How can I find a table cell which contains an element with an input element with a name and apply an attribute to it. e.g. I have a table as below

```
<table>
  <tr><td><input name="someName" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input name="findThisElement"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input name="someName" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

I need to apply border attribute to the td with input element with the name `findThisElement`

```
<table>
  <tr><td><input name="someName" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td style="border:1px solid red;"><input name="findThisElement"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input name="someName" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

I guess I have to use the following statement to apply the css I require but I m struggling to find the td

```
  $(td).attr('style', 'border:1px solid red');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to know about [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

With that in mind, you have 2 options. You can you in a single query the [`:has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and directly apply your css right after :

```
$("td:has(input[name=findThisElement])").css('border','1px solid red');
```

Or you can directly go to the `<input>` and select the [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) `<td>`:

```
$("td input[name=findThisElement").closest('td').css('border','1px solid red');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table input[name='findThisElement']")
```

to apply that style to the parent td of that input element,

```
$("table input[name='findThisElement']").parent().css('border','1px solid red');
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("table")` - this code will return all tables on page

`$("table td")` - this code will return all cells that are in table

`$(table td input")` - this code will return all inputs that are inside cell in table

`$("table td input[name='someName']")` - this code will return all inputs with name `someName` that are inside cell in table

And answer for your question will be : `$("table td input[name='someName']").closest('td').attr('style', 'border:1px solid red');`